# PHPExcel treats first rows as empty although they contain data

Tags: phpexcel

In this following script I'm getting an error that the first 4 rows are empty although I'm using [this spreadsheet](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25322282/Book1.xlsx) which contains data.

Please have a look and suggest what the problem might be:

```
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($path);
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

    $highestRow = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow();
    $highestColumn = $objWorksheet->getHighestColumn();
    $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);
    $nrColumns = ord($highestColumn) - 64;
    $addedtags=0;
    $begin_row=2; // 1st line of data in excel file

    for ($row = $begin_row; $row <= $highestRow;  $row++) {
        $val=array();
        for ($col=0; $col < $highestColumnIndex; $col++) {
            $cell = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
            $val[] = $cell->getValue();
        }

        if ($val[0]<>'') { //check that row contains data before inserting
            $sql1 = sprintf("INSERT INTO ".$dbprefix."terms (name , slug, term_group) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",
               GetSQLValueString($val[0], "text"),
               GetSQLValueString($val[1], "text"), 
               GetSQLValueString(0, "int"));
            $result = mysql_query($sql1) or die(mysql_error());
            echo '<br />Added: '.$val[0];
        } else {
            echo '<br />Error: Line '.$row.' was empty...';
        }
    }
```

I'm using PHPExcel version 1.7.6.

Comment: do you have whitespace preceding the text in the column/row values? ie `  column1`.

Comment: No, I don't. This error happens with any spreadsheet I test it with.

Comment: I'd have to see the actual spreadsheet file to be able to check - what type of file is it?

Comment: It's an xlsx spreadsheet. Here's the actual file I'm using: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25322282/tags-ns.xlsx I also saved it in a 2003-2007 format (xls) but the problem remains.

Comment: You can simplify your code using `$val = $objWorksheet->rangeToArray('A'.$row.':C'.$row);` to eliminate your loop reading individual cells for the row

Comment: Otherwise that file loads cleanly using your code (and simply echoing the sql statements), no missing or empty rows, rows 2-8 all return a result for insertion - so I can't see any problem

Comment: I echo them all out too while testing and rows 2-5 appear empty. I really dont know what the problem might be. The strange part is that I use the very same code (apart from the db insert fields) on other applications and everything works fine. I'm quite puzzled with this one. Anyway, thanks for your effort to help, I appreciate it once again.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `$begin_row` variable from 2 to 1 :

```
$highestRow = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow();
$highestColumn = $objWorksheet->getHighestColumn();
$highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);
$nrColumns = ord($highestColumn) - 64;
$addedtags=0;
$begin_row=1; // 1st line of data in excel file
```

This is an example where they use `$row=1`

http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/393113

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to begin row from zero index if it doesn't contains the headers.

```
$begin_row = 0; // 1st line of data in excel file
```

then $col <= $highestColumnIndex;

```
for ($row = $begin_row; $row <= $highestRow;  $row++) {
    $val=array();
    for ($col=0; $col <= $highestColumnIndex; $col++) {
        $cell = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
        $val[] = $cell->getValue();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

*Just for the record, if someone stumbles across the same problem:*

I observed exactly the described behaviour when I accidentally did not pass an Excel file’s path to `\PHPExcel_IOFactory::load()`, but a *directory* path. So, if you happen to get an unusable value when calling `getHighestRow()`, doublecheck if the path is actually correct.